# Trying to send JSON object from front-end Form-Input to Express backend

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I apologize because this has got to be an elementary-level problem, but after pretty exhaustive searching(including axios' docs), I can't quite find specifically what I need to make this work. Very simply created a To-Do web-app with a front-facing index.html/script.js and backend Express server/API. My todo's need to form an object with key "time:", a 4 digit integer, and key "todo:" with a string. Running console logs on the front is showing empty objects with 'HTML element' in them for the variables inputTime and inputTodo.  I'm getting a successful .then console log on the front end also with an empty response.  My console logs on the express server backend are showing that the server is receiving a POST request, but it's populating an empty object to the global todo array.  I'm including images of code snippets below. The console logs I'm getting in the browser when I submit are:

Initial constructed data is inputTime: [object HTMLInputElement], inputTodo: [object HTMLInputElement] script.js:9:9
Success! [object Object] script.js:16:13

If you guys need to see the server code lmk. Im pretty sure the problem is on the front though because I'm getting good data with postman

Thanks!

```js
document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener("click", submit());

function submit () {

let inputTime = document.getElementById('inputTime');
let inputTodo = document.getElementById('inputTodo');
console.log(`Initial constructed data is inputTime: ${inputTime}, inputTodo: ${inputTodo}`);

    axios.post('/api/todos', {
        time: inputTime,
        todo: inputTodo
    })
       .then((response) => {
    console.log(`Success! ${response.data}`);
    },       (error) => {
    console.log(`There was an error in response ${error}`);
});
}
```

```html
 <div class="container" id="main-holder">
        <form>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputTime">Time</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTime" placeholder="Time">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputTodo">To-Do</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTodo" placeholder="To-Do">
                </div>
                <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Time/To-Do</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: btw I've tried adding .value to the end of the variable declarations and it didn't make much difference other than slightly changing how the empty object was returned in the console log

Answer (score 0):

You should take the value of the input elements. However, you are getting the whole element as variables. Modify like this:

```
  let inputTime = document.getElementById('inputTime').value;
  let inputTodo = document.getElementById('inputTodo').value;
```

Also add your function call to your form:

```
  <form onSubmit="submit()">
```

For further info [check](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Comment: I'm going to look through that link. I really appreciate the help.. I have tried adding the .value to those declarations.. It changes the console log to the following (basically empty after the colon) ..

Initial constructed data is inputTime: , inputTodo: script.js:9:9
There was an error in response Error: Request failed with status code 404 script.js:18:13

postman is showing also empty strings for the global variable 

{
        "time": "",
        "todo": ""
    }
]

Comment: You are welcome. Try adding quotes into your keys:
        `"time": inputTime,
        "todo": inputTodo `.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in the html part in the form element ( i would have never thought..) But I had the form element without any id associated, and when i was clicking submit something to the effect of 2 events were trying to be run at the same time (the default form event and the event i have in the script.js) .. removing the form element entirely solved the problem .. Apparently Form elements have some special characteristics

This code below solved the problem (along with removing the original Form element from the html)

```js
ocument.getElementById('todoForm').addEventListener("submit", submit);

function submit (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
    let time = event.target.elements.inputTime.value
    let todo = event.target.elements.inputTodo.value
    console.log(`Initial constructed data is inputTime: ${inputTime}, inputTodo: ${inputTodo}`);
    const todoObject = {time,todo}

    fetch('/api/todos', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(todoObject)
    }).then(response => response.json()).then((data) =>{
        console.log(data)
        const container = document.getElementById('todoContainer');
        // Create a render function to add the todo to the DOM

    }).catch(e => console.log(`Error is ${e}`))
```

```html
  <div class="container" id="main-holder">
    <form id="todoForm">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputTime">Time</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTime" placeholder="Time">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputTodo">To-Do</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTodo" placeholder="To-Do">
        </div>
        <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Time/To-Do</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```